# Восходящее построение пирамиды на C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Решил улучшить свое понимание некоторых алгоритмов и начал заниматься по книге Левитина. Возникла проблема с реализацией кучи. Сразу привожу код, а потом прокомментирую.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits.h>

void fixup(std::vector<int> &h){
    int j, k, v, n;
    bool heap;

    n = h.size() - 1;
    for(int i = n/2; i >= 1; i--){
        k = i;
        v = h[k];
        heap = false;
        while(!heap && 2*k <= n){
            j = 2*k;
            if(j < n)
                if(h[j] < h[j + 1])
                    j++;
            if(v >= h[j])
                heap = true;
            else{
                h[k] = h[j];
                k = j;
            }
        }
        h[k] = v;
    }
}

int main(){
    int size = 7;
    int in;
    std::vector<int> v(size);

    v[0] = INT_MAX;
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++){
        std::cin >> v[i];
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++){
        std::cout << v[i] << " ";
    }

    fixup(v);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++){
        std::cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Здесь мы рассматриваем каждый узел кроме листьев и проверяем, выполняется ли для него свойство кучи. Если не выполняется, делаем обмен узла со своим максимальным потомком. Потомки узла с индексом `i` в массиве имеют индексы `2i` и `2i+1`, поэтому во внутреннем цикле `while` мы становимся на левого потомка `2i`, и если он меньше `2i+1`, то "указатель" `j` переходит на этого максимального потомка. Затем производится обмен, а как этот обмен реализован, я не очень хорошо понимаю.

Программа работает неправильно: https://ideone.com/hcuvMA

После перестроения массива в кучу узлы расположились не так, как нужно. Правильная последовательность: 10, 5, 7, 4, 2, 1.

Особенности реализации: нулевой элемент массива не используется; сначала массив заполняется элементами, а уже потом преобразуется в кучу.

Comment: Почему вы считаете последовательность 10 7 4 5 2 1 неправильной? Если я правильно понимаю, для нее тоже выполняется свойство кучи: 7 и 4 меньше, чем 10; 5 и 2 меньше, чем 7; 1 меньше, чем 4.

Comment: Да... Видимо, куча строится неоднозначно, и свойство бинарного дерева, когда слева находятся меньшие узлы, не обязательно должно выполняться. В книжке тоже написано, что никаких соотношений между горизонтальными узлами нет.